# How to get the progress when copying a file using BufferedOutputStream & SwingWorker

Tags: java, swingworker

I am copying a file from my computer to an external device, such as an SD card, and I would like to get the progress during the file copying process. I am using SwingWorker so that I can have multiple files copying at the same time. I am not sure how to get the current progress and send it to the SwingWorker publish() method. Here is my code to copy the file:

```
FileInputStream finStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
FileOutputStream foutStream = new FileOutputStream(destFile);

/*
 * Adapted from http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input Output/UseBufferedInputStreamandBufferedOutputStreamtocopybytearray.html
 */
BufferedInputStream bufIS = new BufferedInputStream(finStream);     
BufferedOutputStream bufOS = new BufferedOutputStream(foutStream);

byte[] byteBuff = new byte[32 * 1024];
int len;
while ((len = bufIS.read(byteBuff)) > 0){
    bufOS.write(byteBuff, 0, len);
    publish(/*What do I put here?*/);
}

bufIS.close();
bufOS.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swingworker has already a "progress feature", use it instead of `publish/process`

```
long size = file.length();

int count = 0;
int progress;
while ((len = bufIS.read(byteBuff)) > 0) {
  ...
  count += len;
  if (size > 0L) {
    progress = (int) ((count * 100) / size);
    setProgress(progress);
  }
}
```

Then you can use `worker.getProgress()` in `EDT` or a `PropertyChangeListener` with a progressBar or whatever

E.g:

```
public class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> implements PropertyChangeListener {

    public MyWorker() {
      addPropertyChangeListener(this);
    }

    ....
    /* Your code */
    ....

   @Override
   public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {

      if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
        myProgressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
      }
   }

}
```

Or

```
MyWorker worker = new MyWorker();
worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
            myProgressBar.setValue((Integer) evt.getNewValue());
        }
    }
}
```

If you prefer `publish/process` then `public class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer>` and you will be able to call `publish` with an Integer

Comment: I'm trying your second suggestion with the PropertyChangeListener, but evt.getPropertyName() always returns "state" instead of "progress". Do you know why this is?

Comment: You must call `setProgress(progress);`, in your swing Worker (function doInBackground). Maybe my answer is not clear but you must do first part with one of the second part

Comment: I added getProgress() right after setProgress(progress) and that triggered the PropertyChangeListener.

Comment: It's weird, you don't need to call `getProgress`, but if it works then you can mark my answer

Comment: I took out getProgress and it worked, so I didn't need that. I don't know why it didn't detect the progress event at first but now it does. Well, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. first find the size of the file.
   Use the length method in java.io.File
2. Use the 'len' variable to determine how many bytes have been copied in the current iteration of the loop.
3. Use that data to compute the percentage and use that.

NOTE: The data written may be to the buffer and will be flushed depending upon the size of buffer allocated (this should not hinder the calculation though).

Comment: I tried doing something like that, but I'm confused about what data type I'm passing in since it can't be an int. It needs to be List<FlipPair>, where FlipPair is defined in the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html)

Comment: The class 'FlipPair' mentioned there is part of that sample mentioned in that site. Please see the page https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html that will help you with it.